# Запретить редирект с главной

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Сейчас на сайте стоит редирект через .htaccess с любых страниц на /index.php кроме [robots.txt](http://robots.txt)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

но когда я пытаюсь зайти в корень сайта (/), то он естественно заходит на index.php а потом опять делает редирект и зацикливается. Как отключить редирект для корня (`site.com/`) и файла index.php (`site.com/index.php`)?

UPD

Сделал так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about$ /pages/about.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ /pages/contact.php
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /pages/portfolio.php
RewriteRule ^home$ /pages/index.php
RewriteRule ^blog$ /pages/blog.php [L]
```

А в файле движка сделал проверку: если главная - то редирект на /home

Comment: А как 404 ошибку это сделать если?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не легче ли сделать переход только по ссылкам или поставить.

```
<script>location.href='site_name.ru/index.php';</script>
```

?

Переход только по ссылкам:

```
$block = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strlen($block)>1){
// содержание сайта 
}else{
echo"<script>location.href='site_name.ru/index.php';</script>";
}
```

Comment: А че не header то, а такое извращение? xD